# Sharepoint custom builded webpart is not loading javascript

Tags: javascript, master-page

I am using sp2013. I have builded a visual webpart in visual studio. In this webpart I have a hyperlink. I add some jQuery effect on this hyperlink in custom.js. I load in my masterpage first the jQuery.js file and after this the custom.js. I have checked in the files and publish them. The files are stored in the style library. Here are my script tags in my masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/Style Library/Branding/jquery-1.11.1.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/Style Library/Branding/customJS.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

When I log in with the farm account it is working. When I log in with a normal user with read permissions it is not working. In the IE debugger console tab I see this error:

> SEC7112: Script from
>   http://portal.myCompany.dev/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fportal%2EmyCompany%2Edev%2Fstyle%20library%2Fbranding%2Fjquery%2D1%2E11%2E1%2Ejs&Type=item&name=0d765d12%2D405b%2D4f3c%2Dadf1%2De8647fbb8761&listItemId=56
>   was blocked due to mime type mismatch  Home.aspx
>
> SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined  customjs.js, line 2 character 2
>
> SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some
>   styles were not applied to
>   :visited.  Home.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I faced some issues using the $ sign. Try using jQuery instead of $ in your javascript code.